# Smooks can't find custom decoders that are in a jar on the classpath

Tags: java, smooks

I have several custom Smooks DataDecoders that are set up in a project other than the one I'm working in. I've included the jar for that project on my classpath. Whenever I try to run a smooks config I'm getting this exception:

`DataDecoder Class 'org.milyn.javabean.decoders.com.company.project.decoder.MyCustomDecoderDecoder' is not available on the classpath.`

Comment: I've encountered the same problem. Have you found a solution yet? Thanks.